# If a constructor throws exception, then does it make sense to have a global object of that class?

Tags: c++, exception, global-variables, coding-style

I am asking this question for general coding guidelines:

```
class A {
  A() { ... throw 0; }
};
A obj;  // <---global

int main()
{
}
```

If `obj` throws exception in above code then, it will eventually terminate the code before `main()` gets called. So my question is, what guideline I should take for such scenario ? Is it ok to declare global objects for such classes or not ? Should I always refrain myself from doing so, or is it a good tendency to catch the error in the beginning itself ?

Comment: I think this question is lacking enough context for a sensible answer. What possible exceptions can occur? Just memory (in which case you might as well leave it as it is, as there's no way to start the program if there isn't enough memory), or something more arcane? Exceptions depending on constructor arguments that you can prove never to happen?

Comment: As a "_general_ coding guideline": There is no need for global variables.

Comment: I don't know much about C++. Is `0` a common exception to throw? Because it seems to me you'd be better off throwing an actual exception.

Comment: As a "general coding guideline": You should try to MINIMIZE your use of global variables.

Comment: I agree with Kerrek, there is simply not enough information to provide a yes/no answer - you need to understand your requirement (fail fast or continue in error state) - how critical are these global objects - and why are you using singletons? all of this is relevant...

Comment: did you mean http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10

Comment: Well, I am using the global object **heavily** in my code (you may say it's a bad design, but that is the only way). In fact, I cannot get away with it for some reason. Now, I want to put some exception mechanism in it. So I am stuck there, whether to put exceptions or not.

Comment: It is _not_ the only way. The previous phrase is true with a probability of 999‰ .

Answer (score 4):

If you **NEED** a global instance of an object whose constructor can throw, you could make the variable static, instead:

```
A * f(){

   try {

      //lock(mutex);   -> as Praetorian points out
      static A a;
      //unlock(mutex);

      return &a;
   }
   catch (...){

      return NULL;
   }
}

int main() {

   A * a = f(); //f() can be called whenever you need to access the global

}
```

This would alleviate the problem caused by a premature exception.

**EDIT:** Of course, in this case the solution is 90% of the way to being a Singleton. Why not just fully turn it into one, by moving `f()` into `A`?

Comment: +1 This will work, but you would need to add locks if multiple threads are going to be accessing the global.

Comment: I like this suggestion. It's a form of "construct on first use". But see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15 and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.16.

Comment: @Praetorian: Of course, you'd need locks in that case anyway.

Comment: You can even let the exception propagate and catch it in `main`. If the static variable couldn't get constructed, construction will be retried on next invocation of `f`.

Comment: @Fred Larson You could imagine a scenario where the object takes care of multi-thread access internally. But in the above case you'd still have use a mutex lock during instantiation.

Comment: @Fred: Why "on first use"? Isn't it "construct at the beginning of `main`?" It isn't necessarily being used at all...

Comment: @Kerrek: fred means that it wont be constructed until the first call to `f()`

Comment: @Praetorian Either add locks, or make sure that the first call is before threading has started (or use a C++11 compliant compiler, or use g++).

Comment: @JT: Yeah, I gathered that... it's just a minor nitpick. Usually "construct on use" would have some `getInstance()` function inside which you'd have the static local variable, so that the object would truly get instantiated "on first use".

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Read my links. I didn't name the idiom. It seems apt, though. The object is constructed the first time you use it and no sooner because it's wrapped in an accessor function. You're talking about a singleton, which has more problems associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not declare such objects global - any exception will be unhandled and very hard to diagnose. The program will just crash which means that it will have very poor (below zero) user experience and will be rather hard to maintain.

Comment: Actually, you can do a number of things, depending on your design. If the log tracer is already ready to go, you can log before throwing, for example (and write the log before terminating using a custom terminate hook).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Having the log tracer ready is doable but will require a decent amount of extra wiring.

Comment: Definitely. My recommendation would be NOT to use global variables, or at the very least to postpone initialization to within `main`, but if you work within a framework where more is available to you, then go ahead and use it :)

Comment: @Mathieu M.: Pedantically technically, there is no way to postpone initialization in C++.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kerrek SB has mentioned in the comments, the answer to this is dependent on the reasons that can cause your class to throw. If you're trying to acquire a system resource that might be unavailable, I feel you shouldn't declare a global object. Your program will crash as soon as the user tries to run it; needless to say, that doesn't look very good. If it can throw a `std::bad_alloc` or some such exception that is unlikely under normal circumstances (assuming you're not trying to allocate a few GB of memory) you could make a global instance; however, I would still not do that.

Instead, you could declare a global pointer to the object, instantiate the object right at the beginning of `main` (before any threads have been spawned etc.) and point the pointer to this instance, then access it through the pointer. This gives your program a chance to handle exceptions, and maybe prompt the user to take some sort of remedial measures (like popping up a Retry button to try and reacquire the resource, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a global object is fine, but the design of your class is insignificant, it lacks details to be compatible with practical needs and use.

Answer (score 0):

One solution no one seems to have mentionned is to use a function try
block.  Basically, if the situation is that without the constructed
object, the rest of your program won't work or be able to do anything
useful, then the only real problem is that your user will get some sort
of incomprehensible error message if the constructor terminates with an
exception.  So you wrap the constructor in a function try block, and
generate a comprehensible message, followed by an error return:

```
A::() try
    : var1( initVar1 )
    // ...
{
    //  Additional initialization code...
} catch ( std::exception const& ) {
    std::cerr << "..." << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "Unknown error initializing A" << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This solution is really only appropriate, however, if all instances of
the object are declared statically, or if you can isolate a single
constructor for the static instances; for the non-static instances, it
is probably better to propagate the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Like @J T have said, you can write like this:

```
struct S {
  S() noexcept(false);
};

S &globalS() {
  try {
    static S s;
    return s;
  } catch (...) {
    // Handle error, perhaps by logging it and gracefully terminating the application.
  }
  // Unreachable.
}
```

Such scenario is quite a problem, please read [ERR58-CPP. Handle all exceptions thrown before main() begins executing](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR58-CPP.+Handle+all+exceptions+thrown+before+main()+begins+executing) for more detail.